# Powershell: Resizing windows by title, not by process id

Tags: powershell

I'd like to hear your input on this problem:
I have two Citrix Receiver/Workspace sessions active on my desktop and would like to resize the windows by their window title.

I'm aware of the solution to do this via the process id, e. g.

> Get-Process | Where-Object {  $*.Name -eq 'CDVIEWER' -and
> $*.MainWindowTitle -like 'Window1' }  | set-window -X 0 -y 0 -width
> 3850 -height 1150 -passthru

The problem is that all Citrix Workspace Client windows have the same process id. That leads to the consequence that I can resize only the Citrix Windows that was in the foreground as last.

Is there a way to set the window size by its title and not by its process id?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use native functions [imported from user32.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/) to access the individual windows - i dont think you can do this from powershell alone. Checkout functions `EnumChildWindows`, `GetWindowText` and `MoveWindow` from above link - those are the building blocks of the functionality you require.

The process would be something like

1. Get the `MainWindowHandle` - eg `[System.IntPtr] $WindowHandle =(get-process -Name notepad).MainWindowHandle` (but for the citrix process).
2. Use `EnumChildWindows` with above Handle to locate all its child windows
3. Iterate through the child windows and use `GetWindowText` to find the required window (specifically its Handle). Only look at windows with Handles > 0 - there could be multiple other invalid or invisible windows listed.
4. Use `MoveWindow` to actually change the position of the window (using Window Handle above).

Id suggest you search each of the above and how to execute from powershell rather than trying to [port the API calls to powershell yourself](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/). Using these external functions can be a little tricky, but they are much more powerful.

If you write your own, always use try...catch...finally blocks to make sure you *always* clean up resources. Powershell cant do it for you with these functions. If you open it, close it, if you allocate memory, free it afterwards etc.

I dont have access to Citrix, but above functions should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, MisterSmith!

I'll try it out.